# git reset - ignoring specific untracked files

Tags: git, version-control

Often, I execute `git reset --hard` along with `git clean -f`
in order to clean-up my branch from modifications and build files.
This command, deletes all the untracked files, which is OK for me, but there are few files I want to stay, such as .project or .settings (for eclipse)

These file are not part of the repository, and declared in the .gitignore file.
is there a way to keep these files when issuing the above commands, or maybe I should you different commands for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [`git clean`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) `-f` should only removed files unknown to git, *not* ignored files.

Only `git clean -f -x` would removed ignored files.

(in all cases, a `git clean -n -...` is better, to have a preview of what would be removed)

The advantage of `git reset` over `git clean` is mainly about moving HEAD and resetting the *index* as well as the working tree.
`git clean` is only about the working tree.

Answer (score 4):

[`git reset`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) will not touch ignored files. It works with `HEAD` pointer and index, mostly. But [`git clean`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html) is the evil:

> Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.

So the answer is: do not use `git clean`.